# Strange issue with updating UICollectionView size

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView, which initial height is 50.
I want to update it when I know the size of the cell.
For what I do:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let categoriesCount = 16
    let numberOfItemsInRow = 3
    let numberOfRows = ceil(CGFloat(categoriesCount) / CGFloat(numberOfItemsInRow))

    let newHeight = (numberOfRows * cell.frame.size.height)

    collectionHeight.constant = newHeight
    collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
}
```

But despite of calling `invalidateLayout` - the height of the collectionView stays the same - 50.

But when I switch screens it shows the correct height when I open that screen with UICollectionView for the second time.

What I am doing wrong and how can I update the height of my UICollectionView?

I even tried `collectionView.updateConstraints()` after the `collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout` but still no luck

**UPDATE**

I've tried also

```
collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
self.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()
```

but no result.

Answer (score 0):

For this, you might have to call the `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` method to force the view to update it's layout.

As per the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622507-layoutifneeded):

> ...this method lays out the view subtree starting at the root.

hence, updating your view

For more info, you can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42437966/how-to-adjust-height-of-uicollectionview-to-be-the-height-of-the-content-size-of) thread where you can pick bits and pieces to add to your solution.

Comment: unfortunately I've tried that also and it did not help me =/

Comment: Did you try wrapping the ui manipulations in a `dispatchQueue`?

Comment: I retried your code, and it works fine on my end without any supplementary code. Could you maybe append the rest of the code so we can get a better idea where things might have gone wrong? Also, are you using Storyboards?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to update the collectionView later based on the size of the cell, can we not use [estimated height](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewflowlayout/1617709-estimateditemsize) adjustment of the cell.

Answer (score 0):

Change the Estimated size option in size inspector of collection view to "None" from "Automatic".
See the Image Below for reference.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1h2Bg.png)

I tried many answers given in different threads, none worked in my case but this one.

Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/59783595/11806784 this thread for reference.